# How to set a value in a categorical column of a Pandas DataFrame with boolean indexing?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to alter the value of a categorical column based on a boolean criteria.

I am pretty sure this should be possible using the advanced indexing provided by .loc as demonstrated below, but although this works for rows with a small index, it fails silently for large indices, as you can try yourself by my example below. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.array(range(0, 200)), B=pd.Categorical(['a']*200, categories=['a', 'b'])))

# Setting a categorical with boolean indexing works fine for small indices
print df.loc[df.A == 5]
df.loc[df.A == 5, 'B'] = 'b'
print df.loc[df.A == 5]

print ""

# ... but fails for large indices
print df.loc[df.A == 150]
df.loc[df.A == 150, 'B'] = 'b'
print df.loc[df.A == 150]
```

outputs at my pandas 0.15.1.dev installation (note that the value is correctly updated for A==5, but not for A==150):

```
   A  B
5  5  a
   A  B
5  5  b

       A  B
150  150  a
       A  B
150  150  a
```

Thanks for any hints on what is going wrong. It looks like a bug to me, but I just started with pandas and might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the setitem impl of `Categorical`, and is fixed by this PR [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9470). This will be in the upcoming 0.16.0 release (prob in 2 weeks or so).